# how to addclass when tab is selected and remove all other classes in li elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using a idTabs to build a tab menu and i'm almost there.
But how can i add a class when a tab is selected to the li element **class=current**(which is the parent) if the  anchor is class =SELECTED.
And when the class in the anchor is SELECTED and element li class is CURRENT i want to remove the current from all other li element

Thanks in advance

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#outer ul").idTabs();
});

```
<div id="outer">
<ul class="tabby">
    <li><a href="#Home" class="selected">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#NewPages">NewPages</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
<div id="NewPages" style="display: none;">
    <ul id="subby_NewPages">
        <li>
        <a href="" class="selected">
        <b>Plans</b></a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="">
        <b>Process</b></a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="">
        <b>Stores </b></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="Home" style="display: block;">
    <ul id="subby_Home">
        <li>
        <a href="" class="selected">
        <b>Retail</b></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the first bit is to find the li you're looking for which in jQuery is done using [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). In your case you want a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) for "selected" and then get the parent object (an li). The selection of a parent is described in this [forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/onevent-dosomething-to-parentelement-s-or-sister-elements.).

Your code will look something like the following

```
$(".selected").parent().addClass("CURRENT")
```

Comment: Thanks Neil but the link to the forum doesn't exist

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/onevent-dosomething-to-parentelement-s-or-sister-elements